# Finding Marriage of Elizabeth Smith Julian and Newton Bonner in 1840s Kentucky, North Carolina or Tennessee?

Tags: marriage-records, 1840s, tennessee, kentucky, north-carolina

John Robert Bonner, was born in Missouri, on May 19, 1845.

- His father, Newton Bonner, was born in Kentucky and I don’t know the year.
- His mother Elizabeth Smith Julian is the Daughter of John Julian and Lucinda Burrow Julian Ratliff Born 1828 in North Carolina according to census records.

Apparently several families in Tennessee were thinking of moving West and in 1843 Newton Bonner made a trip to California and back.  Upon his return, they started West into the area of Texas and then turned North with the intention of going to Missouri.  He was what, at the that time, they called a “Scout Master” He would ride ahead of the wagons each day checking the trail and finding a camp site for the night.  No one knows what happened to him, but he rode out one morning and they never saw him again.  Newton Bonner disappeared somewhere in Missouri in 1845 and just a short time before his son John Robert Bonner was born.

A timeline for Elizabeth Smith Julian after that is:

- 1850: Eden, County La Salle, State Illinois, with her son and her mother and step father
- 1853: Married LaSalle, Ottawa, Illinois to "2nd husband Elihu Robinson McCord"
- 1860: Greenville, Bond Illinois with 2nd husband and children
- 1870: She is head of house in Greenville, Bond, Illinois 2nd husband died 1864
- 1880: She is head of house in Greenville, Bond, Illinois
- 1889: Found her in the Indianapolis, Indiana Directories
- 1891: Elizabeth Mccord, "Indiana, Death Index

Newton and Elizabeth's marriage could have been in Kentucky, North Carolina or Tennessee.

Where might I find their marriage record?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Please don't be offended that I have edited and rearranged your question slightly.  This has been done to help focus it in the main question that you seem to be seeking an answer to.

Comment: The Utah, Death and Military Death Certificates, 1904-1961 for John Robert Bonner (20 Apr 1922 at Milford, Beaver, Utah) says that his father Newton Bonner was born in North Carolina (not Kentucky like you write above).  I found that Death Certificate on Ancestry.com.

Comment: For what it's worth, John Bonner's death certificate (Utah, DOD April 20, 1922, found on Ancestry) does state that his father Newton was born in North Carolina. Doesn't mean that it's right :) but that's what it says. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni3Ss.jpg

Comment: I realize this is an old question, so the OP may not still be around... What contemporary evidence do we have that Newton Bonner existed, that his name was Newton Bonner, and that he actually married Elizabeth Julian? His name on JR Bonner's death certificate is third-hand information: JR's widow got it from JR, who presumably got it from his mother, but that doesn't mean it's true. Also, where does the information about Newton's being a scout master / Tennessee / California come from?